# SQL 2008 evaluation expired - how long will the DB continue to work?

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

We've got an instance of SQL Server 2008 running in production and I had no idea it was a trial version - until it expired! Now I can no longer run SQL Management Studio and SQL Reporting Services will not start, *but* SQL Server itself (ie. the database engine) continues running and users can still access data as normal (apart from reports). My question is: how long will it continue to work? Is there a time when it will just shut down and refuse to start again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much the next time you reboot the server, or restart the service it won't start up again.

You can upgrade from the eval to a paid for build by using the /SKUUPGRADE switch when you install the new version from the CD/DVD/ISO.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used the trial but as no one else has answered I would say that this is along the lines of other MS trial products - you can continue to use it until the service/program is restarted.

2008 trial to standard is a supported upgrade path, so unless there are features from enterprise you are using, I would upgrade if possible.